# Saving a data into a .txt file in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a project in Django where I simply count the number of words when I input a sentence. I also try to save the number of words in a .txt file evry time I use the website. 
The views.py is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def count(request):
    fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']

    wordlist = fulltext.split()

    f=open('abc.txt','a+')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(wordlist)
    f.close()

    return render(request,'count.html', {'fulltext':fulltext, 'count':len(wordlist)})
```

The homepage where I give the input sentence is:

```
<h1> Word Count </h1>

<form action = "{% url 'count' %}">
<textarea col='40' rows = '5' name = "fulltext"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type = 'submit' value= 'count!' />
</form>
```

The page where I show the output along with the number of words is:

```
<h1> hey, there are {{count}} words</h1>
<h1> your text </h1>
{{fulltext}}
```

The program runs well in the UI portion. As I give the input sentence in the homepage and submit it, I get the results in the output page. It also generates a abc.txt file in the working directory. However, there is a repetation of the part of the code there as in the .txt file I get the same output twice. That is, if the input sentence is "Tom and Jerry" then the .txt file stores 3 (the number of words in the sentence) twice instead of once. 
Can someone help?

Comment: Are you expecting the word count value to be appended? You would see 3 twice if you submitted to that url twice. (Also your code above shows appending the words, not the word count.)